# Bucket fill won't fill a shape with color in GIMP 2.10.34

Tags: gimp

I have the problem that a *bucket fill* tool won't fill a shape with color in GIMP **2.10.34**.

[image]

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image title in the uppermost part of the GIMP window it appears that the image is **color-indexed**.

Therefore, all colors you try to use are converted to the nearest color in the color map.

You have to convert the image to full-RGB (`Image > Mode > RGB`). This will fix your immediate problem but [can create other problems downstream](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-What-are-color-indexed-images-a-k-a-Why-are-my-colors-all-wrong), although in this case, you could be lucky.